# How to make an API call in Angular HttpClient upon multiple possible triggers without subscribing to the API call method multiple times in my code?

Tags: angular, http, typescript, rxjs, dry

I am making a mildly large Angular Cli app, I have a data table that has a lot of dynamic filters and a search bar and basically and whenever:

```
A) The search value changes
B) The pagination changes
C) A filter is removed or applied
```

I need to make an api call to get the updated table items and the updated filter info.

I have a function in my service that returns the response of the api call which looks something like this...

```
getFilters() {
    const body = { searchTerm: 'foo' }; // 
    return http.post(url, body)
        .map(res => res)
        .catch(err => Observable.of(err);
}

getTableItems() {
    const body = { searchTerm: 'foo', ...stuff for filtering }; // 
    return http.post(url, body)
        .map(res => res)
        .catch(err => Observable.of(err);
}

getApiData() {
    const filters = this.getFilters();
    const items = this.getTableItems();
    return forkJoin([ filters, items ]);
}
```

I also have a lot of other methods that get called, like I said, when pagination changes, or new search term, etc... Basically I'm having to put the `getApiData().subscribe(res => doSomethingWithResponse(res));` in both the constructor, and each method that needs to trigger it like so

```
constructor() {
    ...constructor stuff;
    this.getApiData().subscribe(res => ...);
}
setPageSize() {
    ...stuff
    this.getApiData().subscribe(res => ...);
}
setPage() {
    ...stuff
    this.getApiData().subscribe(res => ...);
}
setSSearchTerm() {
    ...stuff
    this.getApiData().subscribe(res => ...);
}
... and so on...
```

My question is, how can I keep this DRY and still make the API call upon multiple triggers? Is there a way to deal with this issue? Note that I also use `@ngrx/store` (Redux implementation) for storing data on the Front End, and that I'm using rxjs `Observable`'s and `BehaviorSubject`'s in my code.

Comment: Have you considered using @ngrx/effects? You can store state globally, including the results of an API call, and have components subscribe through the store, and trigger events through messages sent to the store (just as you normally would using @ngrx/store)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posts from your API is one source of data in your application. There are sources of triggering events:

1. search value
2. pagination
3. filters

Let's start with printing out posts in your component. There will be some `posts$` observable - a source of posts.

```
<div *ngFor="let post in posts$ | async">{{post}}</div>
```

Let's define such observable in your component.

```
posts$: Observable<Post>;
ngOnInit() {
    const body = {};
    this.posts$ = http.post(url, body);
}
```

Nice but we don't use any parameters, right?

So what are our sources of changes? Let's define them as observables.

```
posts$: Observable<Post>;
page$: Observable<number>;
searchTerm$: Observable<string>;
otherFilters$: Observable<Filters>;
```

Now let's define our sources of events in `ngOnInit()` hook. For sake of simplicity I will focus on pagination and search input only.

```
ngOnInit() {
    // page is probably defined by URL
    this.page$ = this.route.paramMap
        .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => params.get('page'));
    // search term and filters will be probably from some form
    this.searchTerm$ = this.searchTerm.valueChanges
        .startWith('');

    // nothing changed here for now...
    const body = {};
    this.posts$ = http.post(url, body);
}
```

Alright now we want any change of `page$` or `$searchTerm` to trigger new data download. Let's define our `posts$` observable based on `page$` and `searchTerm$`.

```
this.posts$ = Observable.combineLatest(this.page$, this.searchTerm$, (page, searchTerm) => ({ page, searchTerm}))
    .switchMap(params => {
        let body = params;
        return http.post(url, body);
    });
```

Here notice the last argument of `combineLatest`. It is transform function which is called every time something is emitted with values from each observable as arguments. I just create a single object which I will receive later in `switchMap` param.

This is how you can compose observables and subscribe to the final source of data. When you use `async` pipe for subscription it deals with automatic unsubscribe so you dont have to manage it manually. Hope that helped.